# how to reduce loading time of Activity?

Tags: android, xml, performance, android-activity

I am doing following in Activity's onCreate,

```java
if(condition satisfied){
    imageView.setImage(passing view to resize);
    imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else
    imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

resizing like below,

```java
Bitmap bmSource = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), res);
Bitmap bmThumbnail;
bmThumbnail = getResizedBitmap(bmSource, getScreenWidth() / x, (getScreenWidth() / y));
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmThumbnail);
b.setBackground(drawable);
```

In this code I mentioned one view.but in actual code I am having multiple views
This Activity(Consider as A) used as three below,

1. Outgoing Call Screen
2. Outgoing Call connected screen
3. Incoming Call connected screen.

so that I am doing changes in Activity according to that. Using images for speaker,mute,record,etc required for call.

1. OutGoing Call and Call connected Screen,

a)Doing changes for displaying Outgoing call.

b)Once received call acceptance from other person immediately doing screen changes for call connected screen

c)Once screen changes done, timer will be started for call.

2. Incoming Call connected,

a) For displaying Incoming call screen used different Activity.

b) Once user accepts call, then moving to  Activity A.

c) So in Activity A, initially will do some image set up. Once I got response for acceptance  image changes for call connected screen will be done.

So thats the overall process. Now will explain about the problem,

I have mentioned that in both the cases call connected screen changes will be done in Activity A.
In first case, as that already in same screen initial image setup will loaded previously and once got response then changes for Call connected screen will be done. Timer will be started. No problem here.

Problem is ,
When answering Incoming call, it will go to Activity A and Initial image setup. Once got acceptance response will change screen to call connected screen and timer starts. Here it takes time to load initial image setup. So starts timer one sec late leads to different time for Person A and Person B

This problem not occurring in all devices. In Android version 8 I experienced this problem not in above version.

What I meant by Initial Image Setup is setting visibility of imageviews and setting images.

What I have tried,
Instead of using Bitmap used Picasso for resizing and setting image. So that I am able to reduce some 0.20 to 0.25 secs. But image is expanded not proper. In above oreo also reduced some 0.x secs. But also not solved the problem.

Also in log, I have seen this

```
PowerKeeper.Event: notifyActivityLaunchTime: com.package.ex/com.package.ExampleActivity totalTime: 1200
```

1200 mentioned above is milliseconds taken for launching my Activity?? Sometimes getting 1212, 1400

My app works perfect in above O. But oreo and below takes some time to load that affects the call duration. Its really bad. So what can I do??

So how to reduce time taken for doing UI changes in Activity???

***If Anyone find difficulty reading my entire question,then look this short note.***

**Explained Shortly: Consider you are using a calling app(your device is oreo or lower than oreo).And you receive a Incoming call. You tap on answer. Screen will be changed after successfully connected. What if that screen takes some time to load for you while the person in other end got the screen before you? Call duration for you and the other person will be different. So thats my problem**

*****Note: Facing this problem only in oreo and below verions.*****

below is my layout for Activity A.(Used as call connected screen and outgoing call screen)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/call_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/connected_call_background"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/plain_white_bg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/call_swap_merge_transfer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/center_view"
        android:background="#297B88"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/swap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="swapCall" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/merge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="mergeCall" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/transfer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="attendedCallTransfer" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/record_call"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/center_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="callRecord"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/center_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.01dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/after_call_connected_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/center_view"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_dialpad"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/conference_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_dialpad"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/connected_call_root_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingEnd="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialling_status"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/dialling"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15.5sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/call_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hangupoutgoingcall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="hangUpCall" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialerpadbutton_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/callspeakerbutton_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:onClick="speakerOn"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/hangup_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height=".01dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/hangupoutgoingcall"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialerpadbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/hangup_view"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:onClick="showKeypad"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/callspeakerbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/hangup_view"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:onClick="speakerOn"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/callmutebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/hangup_view"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:onClick="muteOn"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/connected_call_keypad_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/dialerpadbutton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-25dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bts1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btzoutgoing" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btzoutgoing"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bth1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btzoutgoing" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bt71"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bts1"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bt81" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bt81"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/btzoutgoing"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bt91"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bth1"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bt81" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bt41"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bt71"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bt51" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bt51"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bt81"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bt61"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bt91"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bt51" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bt11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bt41"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bt21" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bt21"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bt51"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bt31"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bt61"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bt21" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.005dp"
                android:layout_above="@id/bt21"
                android:background="#4B4B4B"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1aaa"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonoutgoing"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonoutgoing"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint=""
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black80"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/contact_nameforoutgoing"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_above="@id/view2"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonoutgoing"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonoutgoing"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint=""
                android:textColor="@color/black80"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonoutgoing"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@id/view2"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText1aaa"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1aaa"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:onClick="removeNumberFromOutgoingNumber"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/add_hold_transfer_record_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/dialerpadbutton"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/hold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="holdOn" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/call_transfer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="unAttendedCallTransfer" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/addcall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:onClick="addCall"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/record_call_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:onClick="callRecord"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:dividerHeight="-1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please anybody help me... Share some ideas to resolve this issue...Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your xml of activity (on which you are facing this issue)

Comment: @Suraj Vaishnav sure will share you with in few minutes

Comment: @SurajVaishnav added xml code..plz look into that

Comment: Are you using pixel images like .png? Maybe you can replace some with vector images. That would help with the file size and scaling. If you need to use regular images, google for "mipmap". The mipmap folder contains the same image at different resolutions and Android will pick the right one for the screen size - thus reducing loading time on old phone.

Comment: @einUsername yes I'm using PNG images...I will try to replace that...thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions:

1. Use `ConstraintLayout`, your xml file contains many views and you are using `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` and these are used in a nested way, so this layout nesting may impact performance.
2. Another thing is while using ConstraintLayout use should use `layout_constraintDimensionRatio` for you `ImageView` to set the imageView height or width according to the aspect ratio of the image which you are going to load.
   So one this is you need to fix either height or width, and the other thing will be calculated by the aspect ratio.

I am just sharing part of `ImageView` code, It would be like this:

> ```
> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
>         
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>     <ImageView
>         
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"  
>         android:layout_height="0dp"> </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
> ```

Note the : `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"`

Also, use glide to load images.

3. And instead of starting a new activity, you should use fragment, we have seen fragment load faster than starting a new activity.

Try the above-mentioned things, and let me know if the issue persists.

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer my question...I will try your suggestions and will check for results 